# Record each pixel polyline is going through in Python Folium

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I have 2 images. One is a map, and the other one is a png overlayed on top of the map with polylines between points, like so:

[image]

How can I "track" a polyline in folium so that I can build an array of pixels the line is going through.

Comment: it can be very big problem to recognize lines on image - and it is not job for Folium but for rather for  `ComputerVison` (module `opencv`) or `Machine Learning` or `Neural Network`.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Something tells me that, whatever your end goal is, front-end 2D raycasting is not the best way to achieve it.